# APEX 4.0 - How to load items when using select

Tags: select, apex

I have a question about APEX, I have the problem that when I try to select a value from a selectbox, no value shows in the other items. What I have tried to do is loading data from the database to the items when I select a code from the selectbox with PL/SQL. How do I do this? Selecting a code from a selectbox and filling all the other items?

Vid

Answer (score 0):

Ok if i understand you right you need a List of Values. 
If you create this shared Object. Use a dynamic list. 
There you have a dialog you can put a PL/SQL or SQL Code snippet into.
You must return a 2 column list. The first Column is the field name in you later select box and the second is you reference.

Comment: I have a list of values. When I select 1 value I want to get all values from the table to be shown in the other items on the same page.

Comment: You select box has a Name. You can you this name as Variable. Like     Select * from sec_table where Referenc_to_firste_table = :select_box_table

Comment: Do I have to use a process or a dynamic action to show the values?